# LXML XPATH - Data returned from one site and not another

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I'm just learning python and decided to play with some website scraping.

I created 1 that works, and a second, almost identical as far as I can tell, that doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://thronesdb.com/set/Core')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

cards = [tree.xpath('//a[@class = "card-tip"]/text()'),tree.xpath('//td[@data-th = "Faction"]/text()'),
              tree.xpath('//td[@data-th = "Cost"]/text()'),tree.xpath('//td[@data-th = "Type"]/text()'),
              tree.xpath('//td[@data-th = "STR"]/text()'),tree.xpath('//td[@data-th = "Traits"]/text()'),
              tree.xpath('//td[@data-th = "Set"]/text()'),tree.xpath('//a[@class = "card-tip"]/@data-code')]

print(cards)
```

That one does what I expect (I know it's not pretty).  It grabs certain elements from a table on the site.

This one returns `[[]]`:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.redflagdeals.com/search/#!/q=baby%20monitor')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

offers = [tree.xpath('//a[@class = "offer_title"]/text()')]

print(offers)
```

What I expect it to do is give me a list that has the text from each offer_title element on the page.

The xpath I'm gunning at I grabbed from Firebug, which is:

> /html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/div/h3/a

Here's the actual string from the site:

```
<a href="/deal/other-kids-babies/angelcare-digital-video-and-sound-monitor-8999-9000-off-9724/" class="offer_title">Angelcare Digital Video And Sound Monitor - $89.99 ($90.00 Off)</a>
```

I have also read a few other questions, but they didn't answer how this could work the first way, but not the second. Can't post them because of the link restrictions on new accounts.
Titles:

- Python - Unable to Retrieve Data From Webpage Table Using Beautiful
  Soup or lxml xpath
- Python lxml xpath no output
- Trouble with scraping    text from site using lxml / xpath()

Any help would be appreciated.  I did some reading on the lxml website about xpath, but I may be missing something in the way I'm building a query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the first code is working is that required data is initially present in `DOM` while on second page required data is generated dynamically by `JavaScript`, so you cannot scrape it because `requests` doesn't support handling dynamic content.

You can try to use, for example, [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) + [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) to get required data as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/path/to/phantomJS')
driver.get('http://www.redflagdeals.com/search/#!/q=baby%20monitor')
xpath = '//a[@class = "offer_title"]'
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
offers = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson!  I was worried that the answer would be super technical and beyond my understanding, but that make sense.  I'll give Selenium a try and see what I come up with.